# How to turn varchar(191) column with predefined values into enum in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table looking as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `User` (
  `id` char(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `role` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'CUSTOMER',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

In all rows of the table, `role` either has the value `'CUSTOMER'` or `'ADMIN'`. I now want to change the type of that column to an *enum* and keep the same data in all rows.

What's the SQL statement to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer myself:

```sql
ALTER TABLE User MODIFY COLUMN role ENUM('ADMIN', 'CUSTOMER') DEFAULT 'CUSTOMER';
```